# Apache Pig CsvExcelStorage

Tags: csv, apache-pig

This is my data:

```
"2001-08-10 01:09:29","3820166553","<P><TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%"><TBODY><TR><TD style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #eee">
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 align=center><TBODY><TR><TD style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #fff" class=maincontent><TABLE style="MARGIN: 0px auto" border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=580 align=center><TBODY><TR><TD colSpan=2><A href="general/forms/YHMN?ci=0c01026bd7fbc394&amp;ags=D778083&amp;cn=KOBY&amp;pfnn="><IMG border=0 alt="Thanks for contacting us click here button" src="http:/edm/tcp-images/yhan-edm-banner-purple_button.jpg" width=580 height=255></A></TD></TR><TR><TD style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 35px; PADDING-LEFT: 32px; PADDING-RIGHT: 32px; PADDING-TOP: 35px" colSpan=2><P style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 18px; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #414141; FONT-SIZE: 14px" align=left></P><P style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 18px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #414141; FONT-SIZE: 14px" align=left>If...",,"778083"
```

**Pig Script:**

```
stage = LOAD '/filename' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',','YES_MULTILINE','UNIX','READ_INPUT_HEADER') as (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5);
col3_data=FOREACH stage GENERATE col3;
DUMP col3_data;
```

**Output:**

```
(<P><TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=100%"><TBODY><TR><TD style=BACKGROUND-COLOR: #eee">
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 align=center><TBODY><TR><TD style=BACKGROUND-COLOR: #fff" class=maincontent><TABLE style=MARGIN: 0px auto" border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=580 align=center><TBODY><TR><TD colSpan=2><A href=general/forms/YHMN?ci=0c01026bd7fbc394&amp;ags=D778083&amp;cn=KOBY&amp;pfnn="><IMG border=0 alt=Thanks for contacting us click here button" src=http:/edm/tcp-images/yhan-edm-banner-purple_button.jpg" width=580 height=255></A></TD></TR><TR><TD style=PADDING-BOTTOM: 35px; PADDING-LEFT: 32px; PADDING-RIGHT: 32px; PADDING-TOP: 35px" colSpan=2><P style=TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 18px; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial)
```

I am using csvExcelStorage to load my data file in pig. One of the column in the file has end of line character. The data file looks like

```
"2015-08-17 23:55:59","12345","<P>this is test data,
<TR>
<\TR><BODY>Text-Align: Arial, Roman,feed this; end of input...","column 4"
```

Load statement is as below :

```
stage=LOAD '/data/file' using csvExcelStorage(',','YES_MULTILINE','NOCHANGE','READ_INPUT_HEADER') as (col1,col2,col3,col4)
```

After loading when I am dumping the data I am getting the below

```
col3 = <P>this is test data,
<TR>
<\TR><BODY>"Text-Align: Arial
```

and

```
col4 = Roman
```

Hence `col3` contains incomplete data and `col4` has wrong data.

Could you please help in identifying what is wrong here.

Comment: Which version of pig ? Can you add the DUMP result of stage alias to the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the above use case, only change made is ref to CSVExcelStorage.Its fetching the expected value for field3.

I believe you have defined an alias as csvExcelStorage to ref. to this class.

**Pig Version : Apache Pig version 0.14.0 (r1640057) compiled Nov 16 2014, 18:01:24.**

**Input :**

```
"2015-08-17 23:55:59","12345","<P>this is test data,
<TR>
<\TR><BODY>Text-Align: Arial, Roman,feed this; end of input...","column 4"
```

**Pig Script :**

```
csvexceldata = LOAD 'csvdata.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',','YES_MULTILINE','NOCHANGE','READ_INPUT_HEADER') AS (col1,col2,col3,col4);
col3_data = FOREACH csvexceldata GENERATE col3;
DUMP col3_data;
```

**Output :**

```
(<P>this is test data,
<TR>
<\TR><BODY>Text-Align: Arial, Roman,feed this; end of input...)
```